# Why I can create these relationships?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create three relationships between tables DATES - SALES - EXPENSES - PL to use a unique slicer from table DATES and filter the charts for SALES, EXPENSES and PL.

Although I can't create a relationship between SALES - DATES or EXPENSES - DATE.
If I create the relationship SALES - DATES then I can't create the relationship EXPENSES - DATES.
The same happens if I try to the relationship EXPENSES - DATES and SALES - DATES afterwards.

Below the message:

[image]

Comment: user relationship function might help, try it!

Answer (score 0):

You already have a Filter Flow path Dates > Expenses > Sort > Sales, and you can't have active relationships that create more than one filter flow path between tables.

One way to resolve this is to remove the bi-directional cross-filtering on the relationship from Sort to Expenses.  Another is to have a separate copy of the Dates table to filter the Sales.